# Derivative of Square Root Polynomial?

Tags: derivatives

How do you find the derivative of

> $\sqrt{x^2 - 4x + 4}$

I applied Chain rule and got this

> $\frac{x-2}{\sqrt{(x-2)^2}}$

However, the fill-in box requires two distinct functions (piecewise) where x > ______ and x < _____.

How would I get two equations from the derivative?

[image: Problem Img]

Comment: First you should write clearly what function you mean: $\sqrt{x^2-4x+4}$ or $\sqrt{x^2} - 4x +4$. Use: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this formatting. Thanks Swapnil.

Comment: Derivative of $\sqrt{x^2 - 4x + 4}$ is nothing but derivative of $|x-2|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\sqrt{x^2-4x+4}=\sqrt{(x-2)^2}=|x-2|$

Comment: At x > 2, y = 1. At 2 > x, y = -1. I understand this part, but would I just plug them in for the piecewise function?

Comment: Yes, and at $x=2$ your function has no derivative. But note the typo for your second case: it should be $x<2.$